# JMESPath in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I have the below json where i want to extract each subset of rules based on the name (example: (SUP) Filesystem usage /var >85%) in my ansible playbook so i can use it as input for my following task.

```
{"nprd_infrastructure_disk_rules": [
      [
        {
          "schemaId": "builtin:anomaly-detection.disk-rules",
          "externalId": "string",
          "scope": "environment",
          "value": {
            "name": "(SUP) Filesystem usage /var >85%",
            "enabled": true,
            "metric": "LOW_DISK_SPACE",
            "thresholdPercent": 15,
            "sampleLimit": {
              "violatingSamples": 3,
              "samples": 3
            },
            "diskNameFilter": {
              "operator": "EQUALS",
              "value": "/var"
            },
            "tagFilters": [
              "Environment:sup",
              "Area:IT"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "schemaId": "builtin:anomaly-detection.disk-rules",
          "externalId": "string",
          "scope": "environment",
          "value": {
            "name": "(SUP) Filesystem usage /var >95%",
            "enabled": true,
            "metric": "LOW_DISK_SPACE",
            "thresholdPercent": 5,
            "sampleLimit": {
              "violatingSamples": 3,
              "samples": 3
            },
            "diskNameFilter": {
              "operator": "EQUALS",
              "value": "/var"
            },
            "tagFilters": [
              "Environment:sup",
              "Area:IT"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
}
```

The closest attempt was the below code:

```
       set_fact:         
         body_nprd: "{{ nprd_infrastructure_disk_rules | json_query(querystr) }}"
       vars:
         querystr: '[][value][?name == to_string(`Filesystem usage /var >95% (SUP)`)]'
```

This gave me the below output where i am missing some fields.

```
  [
    {
      "name": "Filesystem usage /var >95% (SUP)",
      "enabled": true,
      "metric": "LOW_DISK_SPACE",
      "thresholdPercent": 5,
      "sampleLimit": {
        "violatingSamples": 3,
        "samples": 3
      },
      "diskNameFilter": {
        "operator": "EQUALS",
        "value": "/var"
      },
      "tagFilters": [
        "Environment:sup",
        "Area:IT"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

What i want to achieve and get is:

```
      [
        {
          "schemaId": "builtin:anomaly-detection.disk-rules",
          "externalId": "string",
          "scope": "environment",
          "value": {
            "name": "(SUP) Filesystem usage /var >95%",
            "enabled": true,
            "metric": "LOW_DISK_SPACE",
            "thresholdPercent": 5,
            "sampleLimit": {
              "violatingSamples": 3,
              "samples": 3
            },
            "diskNameFilter": {
              "operator": "EQUALS",
              "value": "/var"
            },
            "tagFilters": [
              "Environment:sup",
              "Area:IT"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Your input is showing `(SUP) Filesystem usage /var >95%` while your query is showing you are searching for `Filesystem usage /var >95% (SUP)`, where the `(SUP)` part moved from one end of the text to another. Are you sure all your are showing here is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below

```yaml
  body_nprd: "{{ nprd_infrastructure_disk_rules|flatten|
                 json_query('[?value.name == `(SUP) Filesystem usage /var >95%`]') }}"
```

You can also use [*selectattr*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) instead of *json_query*

```yaml
  body_nprd: "{{ nprd_infrastructure_disk_rules|flatten|
                 selectattr('value.name', 'eq', '(SUP) Filesystem usage /var >95%') }}"
```

both options give what you want

```yaml
  body_nprd:
  - externalId: string
    schemaId: builtin:anomaly-detection.disk-rules
    scope: environment
    value:
      diskNameFilter:
        operator: EQUALS
        value: /var
      enabled: true
      metric: LOW_DISK_SPACE
      name: (SUP) Filesystem usage /var >95%
      sampleLimit:
        samples: 3
        violatingSamples: 3
      tagFilters:
      - Environment:sup
      - Area:IT
      thresholdPercent: 5
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    nprd_infrastructure_disk_rules:
      - - externalId: string
          schemaId: builtin:anomaly-detection.disk-rules
          scope: environment
          value:
            diskNameFilter:
              operator: EQUALS
              value: /var
            enabled: true
            metric: LOW_DISK_SPACE
            name: (SUP) Filesystem usage /var >85%
            sampleLimit:
              samples: 3
              violatingSamples: 3
            tagFilters:
            - Environment:sup
            - Area:IT
            thresholdPercent: 15
      - - externalId: string
          schemaId: builtin:anomaly-detection.disk-rules
          scope: environment
          value:
            diskNameFilter:
              operator: EQUALS
              value: /var
            enabled: true
            metric: LOW_DISK_SPACE
            name: (SUP) Filesystem usage /var >95%
            sampleLimit:
              samples: 3
              violatingSamples: 3
            tagFilters:
            - Environment:sup
            - Area:IT
            thresholdPercent: 5

    body_nprd: "{{ nprd_infrastructure_disk_rules|flatten|
                   selectattr('value.name', 'eq', '(SUP) Filesystem usage /var >95%') }}"

    body_npr2: "{{ nprd_infrastructure_disk_rules|flatten|
                   json_query('[?value.name == `(SUP) Filesystem usage /var >95%`]') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: body_nprd
    - debug:
        var: body_npr2
```

Comment: If I use your solution i get no results in my result. Also i do not want it flattend but remains as a json so i can use it easily in my next task.
{
  "changed": false,
  "ansible_facts": {
    "body_nprd": []
  },
  "_ansible_no_log": false
}

Comment: 1) Update your question and put the complete output of running my playbook. See [mre]. 2) Keep *nprd_infrastructure_disk_rules* in JSON if you want to 3) *nprd_infrastructure_disk_rules* in the playbook is YAML. It's not flattened, and nobody is telling you you should flatten it.